# whether configured files lost while VM instance stopping

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using a google cloud VM instance for my client to configure a web site. Client will not use the site for the next 6 months. For reducing the bill If I stop the VM instance for a period is it affect the configured application in VM instance means the files will lost or not? Also If I start the VM instance again can I get the configured details?

Comment: This question is more suited to Serverfault [1] where it should be asked. Stackoverflow is generally for developers and Serverfault is aimed at system and network administrators). 

[1]: https://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks for your support. I posted in serverfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stop the instance - your disk would be preserved, along with all the files there. You'll be paying just for the storage.

To reduce the cost of storage - consider making a snapshot and store just the snapshot. It cost less per Gb per month and likely would be of a noticeably smaller size then the disk itself.